# Number of partial functions between two sets

Tags: combinatorics

The number of partial functions $A \rightarrow B$ is $(1+|B|)^{|A|}.$ Now either this is a well-known formula, or I just made a mistake in the proof I just wrote. Which is it?

Comment: Looks right to me at first glance.

Comment: The formula is fine. And if your argument is to add an extra element $*$ to $B$ so that $f(a)=*$ means that $a$ is not really in the domain of $f$, then your proof is fine, too.

Comment: Oh, it's that easy..... :(

Comment: If you want, you can post the proof that you wrote, and we can check it; it might be perfectly good, even if it turns out to be more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Nah, it's complicated, uses the binomial theorem, non-standard notation etc. I much prefer your approach!

Comment: :-) Fair enough!

Comment: For what it's worth, the symbol usually chosen (at least in computer science) for the extra element is "$\bot$".